# MySQL Composite Primary Key AutoIncrement

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I am trying to design a database like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `Item` (
   `SKU` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ItemName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`SKU`)
 )

CREATE TABLE `ItemVariant` (
   `SKU` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ItemAttributeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`SKU`,`ItemAttributeID`),
   CONSTRAINT `ItemAttributeMaster_SKU` FOREIGN KEY (`SKU`) REFERENCES `ItemMaster` (`SKU`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
```

I want the auto-increment to work something like this - for each SKU, the ItemAttributeID will auto-increment starting from 1. So I could have

```
SKU|ItemAttributeID|Color
1  |1              |Red
1  |2              |Blue
1  |3              |Green
2  |1              |Purple
2  |2              |Orange
2  |3              |Red
2  |4              |Blue
3  |1              |Green
```

But using auto-increment does not achieve this. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to do it manually, or you could use a trigger...or in the MyISAM engine it works like you want if you use it for the table, but that engine doesn't enforce foreign keys.